# xhr2 multiple file upload using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, client, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload multiple image into a server, using Jquery, with POST method. I tried this code But i'm not able to make it work .Can someone help me to figure out what is wrong with the code. 
Thank you for helping.

```js
function sendData2(){

 
$.fn.upload = function(remote, data, successFn, progressFn) {
 // if we dont have post data, move it along
 if (typeof data != "object") {
  progressFn = successFn;
  successFn = data;
 }

 var formData = new FormData();

 var numFiles = 0;
 this.each(function() {
  var i, length = this.files.length;
  numFiles += length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   formData.append(this.name, this.files[i]);
  }
 });

 // if we have post data too
 if (typeof data == "object") {
  for (var i in data) {
   formData.append(i, data[i]);
  }
 }

 var def = new $.Deferred();
 if (numFiles > 0) {
  // do the ajax request
  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://URL?api_token=fb24085da58dad6decb9271fb170ef2ed8c80617',
   type: "POST",
   xhr: function() {
    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    if(myXhr.upload && progressFn){
     myXhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(prog) {
      var value = ~~((prog.loaded / prog.total) * 100);

      // if we passed a progress function
      if (typeof progressFn === "function") {
       progressFn(prog, value);

      // if we passed a progress element
      } else if (progressFn) {
       $(progressFn).val(value);
      }
     }, false);
    }
    return myXhr;
   },
   data: formData,
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   complete: function(res) {
    var json;
    try {
     json = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
    } catch(e) {
     json = res.responseText;
    }
    if (typeof successFn === "function") successFn(json);
    def.resolve(json);
   }
  });
 } else {
  def.reject();
 }

 return def.promise();
};
}
```

```html
div class="container">

  <form method="post" action="upload.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter the Mune name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="img">Upload menu's image:</label>
      <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="images" placeholder="choose image">
    </div>
<input class="button green" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Content">

  <!--  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> -->
    
      <button type="button" onclick="sendData2()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Menue</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: just by googling the question's title: https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/. Yes, you need some kind of server side service to handle and store the images. The question looks very vague to me. What kind of server are you uploading to? Cloud? Self-hosted? (that is, where do you want the image to be stored) and what would you like to do then? It would be better if you could target a more specific issue and maybe provide some code.

Comment: I added the code i'm using and edited the title, to make it clearer.